# Including spreadsheet in interactive plotly scatterplot

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

Recently I've been using `plotly` to generate beautiful interactive scatterplots where one can navigate and search for specific instances. Then I've saved the result in a html file that can be opened anytime.

I'm wondering if it's possible to include a spreadsheet (potentially in the same generated `html` file) with attached tabular descriptions of the points (so having 2D plot, these would simply be coordinates of XY axes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`go.Table`](https://plotly.com/python/table/)

> go.Table provides a Table object for detailed data viewing. The data are arranged in a grid of rows and columns. Most styling can be specified for header, columns, rows or individual cells.

If you have a scatter and a table trace that are both part of the same figure, both traces will show up when you write the figure to an html file.

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go

x_values = [1, 2, 3]
y_values = [1, 3, 5]

fig = make_subplots(
    rows=2,
    cols=1,
    specs=[[{"type": "xy"}], [{"type": "domain"}]]
)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x_values, y=y_values), row=1, col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Table(header=dict(values=['X', 'Y']), cells=dict(values=[x_values, y_values])), row=2, col=1)

fig.write_html("demo.html")
```

[image: result]

Comment: MANY thanks! This is exactly what I had in mind!